# Pandas find distinct destination where ALL users have visited

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns.  One for users and the other for destinations.
I am looking to find the destination where ALL users visited.  This is the dataframe

```
df1
 user    destination
0  1       dest1
1  2       dest3
2  3       dest4
3  2       dest1
4  2       dest4
5  3       dest1
6  4       dest2
7  4       dest1
8  1       dest4
9  4       dest4
```

Desired Output:

```
dest1
dest4
```

I am working with a dataset with thousands of users and destinations so this must scale out.

Comment: user 5 not visit dest1 and dest4

Comment: Correct and only one user visited dest3 so that would be excluded as well. @Wen-Ben

Comment: So why is `dest1` in the output?

Comment: Because user 1,2,3 and 4 went there.  All users from this dataset. @DanielMesejo

Comment: Theres is an user 5

Comment: Good point, my bad @DanielMesejo  I just fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
# find number of unique users
nunique = df.user.nunique()

# find number of unique users by destination
destinations = df.groupby('destination').user.nunique().to_frame().reset_index()

# find the destinations that match
result = destinations[destinations.user == nunique].drop('user', axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  destination
0       dest1
3       dest4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to unstack() the dataframe converting the users into columns. Then drop any row with an empty column (unvisited).

```
df.groupby(['destination', 'user']).size().unstack().dropna().reset_index().destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for equality between the sets of users grouped by id.

```
users = df.groupby('destination').user.apply(lambda x: np.equal(set(df.user.unique()),set(x)))
users[users]
```

You get

```
destination
dest1    True
dest4    True
```

If you need the destination as array

```
users[users].index

Index(['dest1', 'dest4'], dtype='object', name='destination')
```